# Dynamically added LineRenderer doesn't show in game view

Tags: unity-game-engine

I add some line dynamically and they appear in the scene view perfectly, but not in game view. The z indexes are properly set, I use different layer just for the lines. I tried changing the camera clipping planes values, culling mask is on everything.

[image: unity screenshot]

```c#
void Update()
{
    Vector2 mousePos;

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 closeToPoint = IsClickCloseToPoint();

        if (closeToPoint.z != -10000f)
        {
            GameObject newObj = Instantiate(lineGenerator);
            startMousePos = closeToPoint;
            newLine = newObj.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
            newLine.transform.SetParent(parentObject.transform);
            newLine.positionCount = 2;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        if (newLine != null)
        {
            mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            newLine.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(startMousePos.x, startMousePos.y, -5f));
            newLine.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, -5f));
            distance = (mousePos - startMousePos).magnitude;
            distanceText.text = distance.ToString("F2");
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        if (newLine != null)
        {
            newLine = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the coordinates are different in the scene view and the game view, or at least you have to design to the game view, not the scene view. My lines were present in the game view, but they were out of the canvas. I used Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vektor3) to convert every vektor.

Answer (score 1):

You are drawing everything on a canvas. But LineRenderer is not a UI component and therefore is not shown on the canvas.

If you want to work with LineRenderer nontheless check [this info](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1201050/is-there-way-to-have-line-renderer-on-a-canvas.html) in Unity Answers. The basic idea is to have the canvas set up as Screen Space and increase the width of the lines. Don't forget to assign the camera.

Comment: LineRenderer is an asset in this case, so it doesn't have to be an actual object on the canvas. I just instantiate it.

Comment: So it is a third party UI component?

Comment: @KurdiBoti Instantiating an object adds it to the scene, and I can see it in the hierarchy of your screenshot. It doesn't appear because it is a worldspace object and your game uses a screenspace canvas. You could try using [this](https://gist.github.com/CGPala/d1ace7dddbfbe78cd2de2bb9e40f6393) instead.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to put a material on the lineRenderer. What you see in the scene view is the "non material" texture that doesn't appear in game view :)
I hope that help :)
Raph

Comment: Thanks for the response! Actually I didn't heard that suggestion before, but unfortunately that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the Inspector settings of your LinRenderer but I suspect that you have

[`Alignment`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-alignment.html) set to [`Transform Z`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/LineAlignment.TransformZ.html)

> Lines face the Z axis of the Transform Component.

And thos becomes completely invisible if your orthographic Camera looks exactly in Z direction onto it.

Try and change the `Alignment` to [`View`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/LineAlignment.View.html).

---

Also note that literally **nothing** is rendered on top of a ScreenSpace Overlay Canvas. It is one of the [last things](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) to be rendered in a frame.